# Code does not give errors but does not give results either

Tags: java, geoserver

I try to use [Geoserver-Manager](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager/wiki/Examples). I says:

```
package test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import it.geosolutions.geoserver.rest.GeoServerRESTPublisher;
import it.geosolutions.geoserver.rest.GeoServerRESTReader;

public class RestTester
{

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws MalformedURLException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException
{
    System.out.println("fdfdfd");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String RESTURL  = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver";
String RESTUSER = "admin";
String RESTPW   = "geoserver";

GeoServerRESTReader reader = new GeoServerRESTReader(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
GeoServerRESTPublisher publisher = new GeoServerRESTPublisher(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
System.out.println("fdfdfd");
}
}
```

And there is something interesting. I start this application and get nothing in console. No any errors or my prints.
What can be wrong?  I use Eclipse Galileo.

**UPDATE**

More info
Geoserver Manager add to application how java classes not *.jar files.
I delete all classes from project but RestTester. But still not get any prints in console.

**UPDATE2**

I delete RestTester class. And add new class `HelloW`.

```
public class HelloW
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("HelloW");
}

}
```

Run it and get error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloW
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloW
```

But when i create new project with same class all works fine. In project where i try Geoserver Manager i add some *.jar but its was only `apache commons` and `jdom` libraries, half of then i use in my another applications.

Comment: What's your expected result? What result do you get? Does your server get hit?

Comment: Seems that your `main` method is never called.

Comment: Are you sure RestTester is your main class?

Comment: There are two SOPs present in the main method atleast the first one should get printed. What happens if you remove the `reader` and `publisher` instantiation statements?

Comment: Yeah RestTester my main class. But why its can be never called? How can i check it? If i remove everything but print i dont get result too.

Comment: Click on the down arrow button near the `play` button to run application and select your `RestTester` class manually. If it stills showing nothing, let us know.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX: I already try it, nothing heppens too.

Comment: You said that `Geoserver Manager` is added with java classes and not a jar file. Did you check that these files does not have a `main` method? Probably your IDE thinks that your `main` class is one of those files that have a `main` method. I don't know, I'm just giving suggestions.

Comment: @ DaGLiMiOuX: I delete all classes from application but RestTester. But not get resullt too.

Comment: Well, that's REALLY strange :S Last thing I can suggest you is that check if your IDE has crashed for some reason. I mean, restart it and try to run the app. If it stills not working create a new blank Java project, with a predefined main class, write some `System.out.println` and try to run it. If it stills showing nothing... you can select eclipse folder by clicking it and press `del` xD

Comment: you can try to run your test class manually, try: `java test.RestTester` in your output directory

Comment: @ DaGLiMiOuX: I update question/ Please look at it.

Comment: @KliverMax O.o?! wow... I recommend you to save what you have done in a folder or something, delete your project and create a new one (delete it with right click > delete > check also delete folder from workspace, go to workspace and check that your folder was deleted). Then, create a new project at your workspace and copy **ONLY** the code from your Java files, **DO NOT COPY** your java files into the new project folder. And give it a try. Thats what I did when something like that happened to me and sometimes worked, because IDE crashed or something.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX: I create new project add same *.jar and Geoserver Manager, then write same code that in RestTester and...its works. Magic?

Comment: @KliverMax hahaha it's not magic xD It's only IDE crash. Sometimes, eclipse gets bugged for some reason, thats why I prefer NetBeans. Also, because I find NetBeans much faster than eclipse, in my opinion. However, if you prefer to work with eclipse and this happens to you another time, you know the solution ;D

Comment: @KliverMax You are welcome! ^^